# CSS style with four div in addition to the container DIV

Tags: html, css

I would like to write a CSS script that involves 4 div in addition to a fifth div  as a container.

The Div 1 should be at the top as a title, Div 2 should be at the  center of  the right side of the container ,Div 4(Containing img src) should be at the center of the container , and Div 3 should be at the bottom of the image.

I had a script as a trial but it not like that  I want( Iam beginner in CSS) .

[image: like this image]

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

<head>
<title>    </title>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>

    #siena img {

        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 0px;

    }

    #Container
    {
        margin-bottom: 3pc;
        text-align: center;
        border-width:2px;
        border-color: #46b8da ;
        margin-right: 100px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        border-style: solid;
        background-color :#c4e3f3;
        padding :10%;


    }
    #link
    {
        display: inline-block;

    }
    #price
    {
        top:100px;
        width:50%
          margin:0 auto;
        float:right;
    }
 </style>
 </head>

  <body>


  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <h1  style="text-align: center;">   Text   </h1>



  <div id="Container"  >  <p>
    <div id="siena" >
     Text 

   <img src='http://www.traidnt.net/vb/attachments/480574d1272729780-no_pic.gif'>
          <div id="price" >
            price 
        </div>


    </div>

    <div id="link" >
        <a href='https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl' > </a>

    </div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need both html code and css code to make it work, can you show us what you've done thus far?

Comment: To help you understand where you went wrong, I created this [colorcoded jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/7tzce63q/). I recommend adding background color to the different DIVs in the future to easier understand/learn how to build with DIVs and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to copy the image in css

```css
.container{
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  height: 500px;
}
.top, .bottom{
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.left, .right{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid maroon;
  height: 200px;
}
.right{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

**Edit** since you asked about the image overlapping another div.

The following will make it so the image will not extend past it's container so the image wont overlap any other div.

```
.left img{
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
}
```

Is that what you meant?

Comment: the image might overlap with another divs how to avoid that?

Comment: I added a section to the answer. Basically including `max-width: 100%` to the img to prevent the img from overlapping another div. was it helpful?

Comment: Nice. also I want the text on the top div to be at the bottom, and the text on the right div at the left side of it how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your markup looks invalid.

You have unecessary spaces within tags and unclosed `p` tags.

You can achieve what you want via this markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">Div 1</div> 
    <div id="content">Div 4</div>
    <div id="side-content">Div 2</div>
    <div id="footer">Div 3</div>
</div>
```

And then use `CSS` to position the elements:

```
#container {
     width: 100%;
}

div {
    border: 1pt solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

#content {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7dqagh7s/

Also, I would recommend using a StyleSheet rather than putting the code directly inline with the markup.